# Discord Bot Javascript Commands Else If Problem

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, bots

i was building my discord bot, i wanted to make a currency command for 2 people : me and my friend. i was adding the `if else statements` and it worked fine for me, but i swapped the `ID`s to test if it would work for my friend, i added the statement `"else if"` and then the `"else"` was a problem, it said `"Declaration or statement expected."` but i did it correctly, there is too much code in the whole file so i'll only send the thing :

```
// >bal
case 'bal':
                if(userID==603873287071858701) {
                    bot.sendMessage({
                        to: channelID,
                        message: bal2
                    }) 
                    else if(userID==546721227671076864) {
                        bot.sendMessage({
                            to: channelID,
                            message: bal1
                        })
                    }
            break;
```

oh, and by the way, yes, i did add the values : `"bal1, bal2"` so it isn't that problem, i tried removing the "else", but that didn't do anything, btw the ID that starts with a 5 is my `userID` and the `ID` that starts with a 6 is my friend's id, i swapped them to test if it would work for my friend. what do i do to fix this problem? btw i'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Your if-statement has a opening bracket `{`, but not a matching `}` to close the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgat to close (`}`) the `if` statement before the `else if` statement. if it doesnt working try to log `userID` before the `if` statement to debug it.

Comment: lol you are welcome :) ( if you can to vote up it will be nice :) )

Comment: @ינוןרחמים Questions caused by typographical errors [should be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) instead of answered, because they are very unlikely to help people beyond the OP.

Comment: Only the person who downvoted you can tell, but it seems likely.